# How to merge each user object to an observable of an array?

Tags: javascript, firebase, rxjs

My question is, **which map operators should I use to convert each object to an array?**

First of all, I retrieved users keys from friends node like the image below.

[image]

I'd like to use those keys to get my friends list from users node. But, the result returns as separate objects like the image below.

[image]

Therefore, I can't iterate those data to display the view.

I'm not sure even this approach is the correct way of doing it or not.

Here's the code what I've done so far.

```
    getMyFriendList() {
      this.userService.getMyFriendKeys().switchMap(data => {
        console.log('TEST', data);
        return data;
    }).subscribe(friend => {
      this.userService.getFriends(friend.key).subscribe(res => {
        console.log('TEST2', res);
        // res is an objects
      });
    });
  }
```

friends.json:

```
{
  "5NnRVze6TVUeunLV0KXVmLby03J2": {
    "VkwT5IgS7ZYqDZ4uz5Dh76inrAK2": true,
    "dm8o0podI3gou0ob3wirkiyOGOu1": true
  },
  "VkwT5IgS7ZYqDZ4uz5Dh76inrAK2": {
    "5NnRVze6TVUeunLV0KXVmLby03J2": true
  },
  "dm8o0podI3gou0ob3wirkiyOGOu1": {
    "5NnRVze6TVUeunLV0KXVmLby03J2": true
  }
}
```

Users.json:

```
{
  "5NnRVze6TVUeunLV0KXVmLby03J2": {
    "currentActiveStatus": "online",
    "displayName": "Jeff Kim",
    "email": "ziznzkak@gmail.com",
    "photoURL": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/chattycherry-3636c.appspot.com/o/user-default.png?alt=media&token=f85be639-9a1c-4c79-a28d-361171358a41",
    "statusMessage": "",
    "uid": "5NnRVze6TVUeunLV0KXVmLby03J2",
    "username": "helloworld"
  },
  "VkwT5IgS7ZYqDZ4uz5Dh76inrAK2": {
    "currentActiveStatus": "offline",
    "displayName": "John Doe",
    "email": "hahehaheha@naver.com",
    "photoURL": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/chattycherry-3636c.appspot.com/o/profilepics%2FVkwT5IgS7ZYqDZ4uz5Dh76inrAK2?alt=media&token=e9c2a8dc-5a10-42a7-a9c9-b28d53776f12",
    "statusMessage": "programming is awesome!",
    "uid": "VkwT5IgS7ZYqDZ4uz5Dh76inrAK2",
    "username": "hello"
  },
  "dm8o0podI3gou0ob3wirkiyOGOu1": {
    "currentActiveStatus": "offline",
    "displayName": "Sia ",
    "email": "ziznzkak4@daum.net",
    "gender": "Female",
    "photoURL": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/chattycherry-3636c.appspot.com/o/profilepics%2Fd65DhlrcCGaayOBaF2siVhauQbq1?alt=media&token=19e2b040-0fd9-4f59-9d56-406a817f58a3",
    "statusMessage": "Hmm?",
    "uid": "dm8o0podI3gou0ob3wirkiyOGOu1",
    "username": "hellowo"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide the json format of the body returned by  `getMyFriendKeys()` properly. and the one of returned by `getFriends()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by myself. I should have used combineLatest() method.
First, pull two different object observables from firebase and then combine friends object observables to a new observable called `this.friends`. This results in an observable with an array that I can iterate over in the template.

Thank you for your help CozyAzure.

```
    getMyFriendList() {
      this.userService.getMyFriendKeys().switchMap(data => {
        return Observable.combineLatest(data.map(x => this.userService.getFriends(x.key)));
    }).subscribe(friends => {
        this.friends = friends;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

If you want to call `getFriends()` on parallel and fetch all of the details of friends, you can use `Observable.forkJoin()`:

```
this.userService.getMyFriendKeys()
    .switchMap(data => {
        return Observable.forkJoin(Object.keys(data).map(x => this.userService.getFriends(x.key)));
    })
    .subscribe(friends => {
        //friends is an array of items
        console.log(friends[0].displayName)//gives John Doe
    })
```

The trick is to use `.map()`to return an array of Observables after you called `.getMyFriendKeys()`. Note this `.map()` is a function of array, not observables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer CozyAzure. But nothing prints out on the console.

Comment: Can you check if the service is getting the data? Check the network tab in your console. Also it is good if you can provide the json format of your data structure

Comment: I have edited your question and updated my answer too

Comment: Still, it gives nothing :(

Comment: @JeffMinsungKim you need to check your network tab if those services are fired. Note that Observable.forkjoin() would wait **all** http request to complete before it would emit an emission

Comment: Object.keys(data) this will give an array of ["0", "1"]. So if you Object.keys(data).map(x) x will be 0 and 1. x.key does not exists.

Comment: I think the services are fine. But the approach of getting the keys aren't valid. Your first approach was correct I guess. Not sure how to check the network. :(

Comment: So does your `getMyFriendKeys()` returning an array or an object?

Comment: No, it returns nothing.

Comment: I mean `getMyFriendKeys()` is returning an array or an object?

Comment: Yes getMyFriendsKeys() returns an array. It returns exactly the same as the image I've posted it.

Comment: Then it is not the same as the json you gave. In that case, you do not need to use `Object.keys()`. Could you create a plnkr or jsbin? It's easier to see what is the problem with those

Comment: I've just posted an answer that I've found. You helped me a lot CozyAzure. Thank you!